# AlarmManager to restart my android application

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to have my AlarmManager somehow call onCreate on my main activity in the application.

Also, I'm setting the event from the same class. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlarmManager works with `PendingIntent`s, which intern are based on regular `Intent`s. If you register an `Intent` that starts one of your activities, it will be started and `onCreate` will be called in the process. Check that you are using the proper flags, and keep in mind that popping activities out of nowhere while the user is doing something else, might not be a good idea.